# RegEx: found all comments but not within quotation marks

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, regex

I have thought of an example that I can use to learn it well. I designed a kind of "script language" (as a string) that I want to parse and interpret.

PS: Yes, it reminds of LINQ a bit, but that's just a coincidence.

The first thing I thought about, I want to remove all the comments, because these shouldn't be interpreted.

I only look for comments like: `/*...*/` and `//...\n`

However, these should of course not happen within quotation marks: `"..."` and `'...'`

But how can I use RegEx to find comments that are not inside quotation marks?

**String:**

```
  //get means only read, but not to mutate data
  Get(BooksWithAuthors)
    //default queries via mycel
    .Query()
      //junction table to pair books and authors
      .From(BookAuthor.As(BA))
      //main table for books
      .Join(left: Books.As(B) => B.Id == BA.BookId)
      //main table for authors
      .Join(left: Authors.As(A) => A.Id == BA.AuthorId)
      //groups by column, body allows to restore data (restructuring)
      .GroupBy(B.Id, => B.Authors.Add(A))
      //ignore still registerd data objects for the response
      .SelectIgnore(BA)
      //or select only that fields or objects you want to response
      .Select(B)
      .Foo("//wrong-comment-inside-quotes")
      .Foo('//wrong-comment-inside-single-quotes')
      .Foo('some /*wrong-comment*/ inside')
  ;

  //get means only read, but not to mutate data
  Get(BooksWithAuthorsByMethod)
    //using individual backside methods (created by own)
    .GetBooksWithAuthors(id:6, filter:{key:'minAuthorAge', value:17})
  ;

  /*
    comments
    "over"
    'multiply
    lines' //with wrong comments inside
  *\
```

**RegEx:**

```
.*[^'"].*([\/]{2}.*[\r\n|\r|\n]).*[^'"].*
```

(https://regex101.com/r/zPzBFj/1)

Yeah, I tried it only with `//`, but not every incidence was found and it also matches that comments within quotation marks. Maybe `?!` is not the right way. But how can I do that?

I'm sure I'll have one or two more questions about this example. But as I said, I'm still learning RegEx, so step by step...

Comment: [this](https://regex101.com/r/Wvl3Wq/1) regex can be of some help? the problem with `negative lookbehinds` is that must be of fixed width (so you can't use quantifiers inside it)

Comment: You say, "The first thing I thought about, I want to remove all the comments, because these shouldn't be interpreted." Is that what you want to do? I read "The first thing I thought about" as meaning you decided you want something else, but haven't made clear what you want. btw, do you have any suggestions for removing a fly from my computer screen?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The target is to parse that whole input via C#.NET. And because comments don't have to be parsed, I try to remove the comments, but only these which are not within quotation marks. The best way would be to have only one group with matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you match the string with the regular expression

```
/'.*?'|".*?"|(\/\/[^\r\n]*|\/\*.*?\*\/)/gs
```

comments will be saved to capture group 1. The idea is to match but not capture what you don't want and match and capture what you do want. Pay no attention to matches that are not captured.

Without the `DOTALL` flag (`/s`) periods match all characters other than line terminators; with that flag set periods match all characters, including line terminators.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GhBbUK/1)

At the demo link matches that are not captured (not comments, so disregard) are shown in blue, whereas matches that are captured (comments) are shown in green.

---

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
'.*?'       # match a single-quote followed by >= 0 chars, lazily,
            # followed by a single-quote
|           # or
".*?"       # match a double-quote followed by >= 0 chars, lazily,
            # followed by a double-quote
|           # or
(           # begin capture group 1
  \/\/      # match '//'
  [^\r\n]*  # match >= 0 chars other than line terminators
  |         # or
  \/\*      # match '/*'
    .*?     # match >= 0 chars, lazily
    \*\/    # match '*/'
)           # end capture group 1
```

---

Here is an example of how this works. Suppose the string were as follows.

```
A dog "is // a\nman's" /* best */ 'friend /* so it */ is' // said
```

The regex engine performs the following steps.

- Fail to match `A`.
- Fail to match   after `A`, then fail to match `d`, `o`, `g` and  .
- Match but do not capture `"is // a\nman's"`.<sup>1</sup>
- Fail to match  .
- Match *and* capture the comment `/* best */`.
- Fail to match  .
- Match but do not capture `'friend /* so it */ is'`.
- Fail to match  .
- Match *and* capture the comment `// said`

<sup>1. After this match the regex engine's string pointer is between the (last) double-quote just matched and the following space.</sup>

Comment: This is kewl and it seems like that's it! :)

Comment: Are you familiar with C#.NET?
 ---------- 
Because when I use `Regex.Replace(myString, pattern, "");` then only the first group is executed. How do I use `Regex.Replace()` to replace only the matches from the second group? I switched it to `/(\/\/[^\r\n]*|\/\*.*?\*\/)|'.*?'|".*?"/gs`, but that doesn't help. I mean, in the sample it works, but I need to remove all comments (but not these inside a quoted string). :/
 ---------- 
Otherwise I'll have to post another question to ask specifically C#.NET developers.

Comment: Sorry, but no, I don't know C#.NET. However, the regex I suggested is to extract captured matches, not to replace anything. Do you wish to return a string that contains just the comments or everything other than the comments, or an array of comments? Does C# have a method/function that could be used in place of `Replace` that would be more suitable? Perhaps a reader who knows C# can answer your question.

Comment: Perhaps something like the following (which is a mix of C# that I've seen elsewhere and pseudocode, admittedly, a dog's breakfast) could be used to collect the comments in an array `arr`: `arr = []; Regex regex = new Regex("..."); foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(text)) { arr.append(m) if vm.Groups[1].Value != nil; }`.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. But is it possible to get it in only one group? I tried it, but can't find a way: https://regex101.com/r/S1ypvu/1 The problem is that there could be chars between `"` and `//` or `/*`. So the negative lookbehind can't consider the characters between.

Answer (score -1):

This returns what you're looking for in the example, let me know if you find any edge cases. You'll have to post-process the matches based on whether it's a comment or quoted string.

```
(?:(?:(\/)(\*)|(["'])).*?(?:\2\1|\3))|(?:\/\/[^\n]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/uqx1cJ/1

Comment: Okay, that finds all comments and quoted strings.

But I'm looking for all comments which can contain quoted strings, but not if the comment by self is contained in a quoted string. 

You know? ^^

Comment: It doesn't find the ones contained in quoted strings/comments. Only the valid ones.